# i am not able to add color to my counter project

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am creating a counter project which increase reset or decreases the count when respective button is clicked and colour of count also changes for postive negative and zero value of count but i am unable to change colour of count if it is positive, negative, zero but my code just performs when count is zero.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./counter.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Counter<h1>
        <h1 id="counter">0</h1>
    <div>
>       <ul>
            <li id="decrease"><button>DECREASE</button></li>
            <li id="reset"><button>RESET</button></li>
            <li id="increase"><button>INCREASE</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="counter.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

```
const decrease = document.getElementById("decrease");
const increase = document.getElementById("increase");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
var count = 0;

decrease.addEventListener("click", function(){
    count -= 1;
    counter.textContent = count;

});
increase.addEventListener("click", function(){
    count += 1;
    counter.textContent = count;
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
    count = 0;
    counter.textContent = count ;
});
 counter.style.color = colour();
    function colour(){
        if (count === 0){
        return "blue";
    }
    if(count > 0){
        return  "green";
    }

    if(count < 0){
        return "black";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question not an image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] and also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You have an issues in the way you are trying to update `color` that is the reason it is not being updated. Instead of calling function on every click, you are just running it single time and hence the issue. You should create a function to update color and call it after updating counter in all 3 click handlers.

```js
let count = 0;
const elemCounter = document.getElementById("counter");

function increase() {
  count++;
  updateCount();
}

function decrease() {
  count--;
  updateCount();
}

function reset() {
  count = 0;
  updateCount();
}

function updateCount() {
  elemCounter.innerText = count;
  updateColor();
}

function updateColor() {
  let color = "blue";
  if (count > 0) {
    color = "green";
  } else if (count < 0) {
    color = "red";
  }
  elemCounter.style.color = color;
}
```

```css
#counter {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<button onclick="increase()">Increase</button> <br />
<button onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button> <br />
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```